# Not sure how to repeat while loop - PYTHON

Tags: python, while-loop

All the logic of the program is okay, the program takes the user input and prints an error if the user inputted anything other than a integer, but im not sure how to get the program to loop if the user enters an invalid input.

```
Passlimit = 10


    while Passlimit:
        try:
           Passinput = int(raw_input("how many characters and numbers would you like for your password to contain? NO LONGER THAN 10 CHARACTERS:   "))
           if not (Passinput <= Passlimit):
               raise ValueError()
        except ValueError:
            print("Invald input, Please only input numbers")
        else:
            print("NUMBER SELECTED")
        break
```

Comment: What is `Passlimit`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Beginner python loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44674222/beginner-python-loop)

Comment: The limit to how many characters the password could be

Comment: Why is `while Passlimit:` indented more than `Passlimit = 10` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `break` is immediately following the `try...except...else` clause. I think you meant to indent the `break`, so that it is only executed in the `else` branch.

You would still need to add code though to keep track of the number of tries, otherwise it will loop indefinitely as long as the user provides invalid input.